# cgminer not working on deepbit.net

Tags: mining-pools, miner-configuration, cgminer

I installed Cgminer and created the batch file to run it

`cgminer.exe -o http://pit.deepbit.net:8332 -u myemail@gmail.com_workerName -p s3cr3t`

but when I run it I get

```
[2013-05-21 00:39:34] Started cgminer 3.1.1  
[2013-05-21 00:39:34] Probing for an alive pool  
[2013-05-21 00:39:38] Pool 0 slow/down or URL or credentials invalid  
[2013-05-21 00:40:34] No servers were found that could be used to get work from .  
[2013-05-21 00:40:34] Please check the details from the list below of the servers you have input  
[2013-05-21 00:40:34] Most likely you have input the wrong URL, forgotten to ad d a port, or have not set up workers
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: People who closed this question: Please leave a comment so that the person who asked it knows what was wrong about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the author of this question and it worked when I tried again next day.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Lohoris He is the author.

Answer (score -1):

Replace the workerName with a worker name for your account

Comment: Could you clarify your answer? I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: I use the same command without problem. Take care one the user name or pass (seam be wrong). You can too test: http://pit.deepbit.net:8332 into your web browser to check the connectivity.